# How should I number my lines in my OrderLines table in Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access, data-structures

I have been searching for this for weeks and I am wondering if I am barking up the wrong tree or if I am just missing something.  I am creating a database in Access.

The structure is as follows:

tblOrderDetails 
.ORDERID .DEALER  .CREATEDATE 
   4051    Willow    4/17/18
   4052    Oak     4/17/18

tblOrderLines
.ROWID .ORDERID .PRODUCTSKU   .ORDERLINENUMBER
 1     4051     Desk          1
 2      4051     Chair          2
 3     4052     Dresser         1
 4      4052     Chair          2

Hopefully that all makes sense.

ROWID and ORDERID are auto generated Access numbers.  I am using them as the primary key so the tblOrderDetails.ORDERID is 1:n tblOrderLines.ORDERID.

My question is in regards to the Order Line Number.  Currently, I am using a query to generate the line number when the labels and the packing slips are printed, but it seems like this is not best practice.

Is there some way that i can use SQL or some access function to create a sequential number that restarts for every new order.

Comment: I'm not getting you.  The concept for generating the `OrderLineNumber` and `BoxNumber` is the same as an autonumber.... ok.  So each new record will get a number.  They will start at 1 and each record will increase the autonumber by 1.  Also, not sure what version you're using - do later than 2010 versions allow for non-numeric autonumbers?  You say the ID fields are generated using autonumbers, but `OrderID` is `OD1` and `BatchID` is `SP1`?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, sorry that I wasn't clear.  I meant that the concept for generating a OrderLineNumber would be the same as generating a BoxNumber. <br/> I am using Access 2016.

Comment: The data I typed in isn't real i typed it in for demonstration purposes.  The "SP" and "OD" are not in my database.  Ill edit my post to make it more clear.  I need the Order lines to count up and restart at each new order.  So it is giving me a line number for each line of my order.

Comment: Ah, right.  Get you now.  AutoNumber won't increase the numbers like that.  So `OrderID` is the Primary Key for `tblOrderDetails` & a Foreign Key in `tblOrderLines`, `RowID` is the Primary Key for `tblOrderLines`.  `OrderLineNumber` is an ordinal number for the products being sent to the dealer.  `OrderLineNumber` should be generated when the product is added to the table I take it?

Comment: Correct.  I have worked in databases in the past that i am pretty certain had this value.  I cannot figure out how to generate it at the table level.  i can generate it in a query but I would like to store it in a table.  In the scenario above my customer "Willow" may want to add a dresser to order 4051, when i add their new line I need the OrderLineNumber to be 3.

Comment: I'm thinking you'll need a custom function that's attached to the default value of a form control - you can't use custom functions on the default value of a field in a table.

Answer (score 0):

This code will give the next Order Line Number for an Order ID.
I *think* you'll have to put it as the default value for a form control, or maybe in the *after_update* event.
I'm not sure - have a play around.

```
Sub Test()

    MsgBox NewOrderLineNumber(4051)

End Sub

Public Function NewOrderLineNumber(OrderID As Long) As Long

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", "PARAMETERS Order_Identifier Long; " & _
                                   "SELECT COUNT(OrderID) AS CurrentCount " & _
                                   "FROM tblOrderLines " & _
                                   "WHERE OrderID = Order_Identifier")
    With qdf
        .Parameters("Order_Identifier") = OrderID
        Set rst = .OpenRecordset
    End With

    With rst
        If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            NewOrderLineNumber = .Fields("CurrentCount") + 1
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: I created a Form for my tblOrderLines.  I set the OrderLineNumber column's default value to =NewOrderLineNumber([OrderNumber]).  Then i also created an Unbound text box and set it equal to =NewOrderLineNumber([OrderNumber]).  The bound column is returning null.  The unbound text box is returning the number 5.  Can you tell what i might be doing wrong?